# Remove/Modify domain property using metaclass

Tags: grails, groovy, metaprogramming

There is a domain which contains a static property:

```
public static fieldNames = ['fieldName','fieldName2']
```

The code is :

```
def fieldNamesProperty = grailsApplication.getDomainClass("domainPackage....domain").getPropertyValue('fieldNames')

if(fieldNamesProperty){

// do something

} else{

// do something

}
```

In the spock test I want to test the else part but I can't change the domain directly so I want to use metaclass to remove fieldNames property from domain name or set it to null only for testing. Is it possible ? I know how to override a method using metaclass but no idea about removing/overriding property.

Update:

```
    DomainClass.metaClass.static.getFieldNames = { ['category'] }
    def fieldNameProperty = grailsApplication.getDomainClass("...DomainClass").getPropertyValue('fieldNames')
```

returns null

Also tried:

```
DomainClass.metaClass.getFieldNames = { ['category'] }
DomainClass className = new DomainClass()
println className.fieldNames
```

throws missingPropertyException

Also tried without using .static.

Answer (score 1):

Because Groovy properties, by their nature of being properties, have getter and setter methods, you can use the MetaClass to override the getter method.

## With domain class

```
SomeClass.metaClass.static.getFieldNames = { [] }
```

Here's a demonstration using a plain Groovy class which you can adapt to a Grails domain class.

```
class SomeClass {
    static fieldNames = ['fieldName','fieldName2']
}

SomeClass.metaClass.static.getFieldNames = { [] }

def fieldNamesProperty = SomeClass.fieldNames

if(fieldNamesProperty) println 'Got some field names'
else println 'No field names'
```

In this example, the *else* branch will execute since an empty list evaluates as *false*.

## With GrailsDomainClass

If the `GrailsDomainClass` returned by `grailsApplication.getDomainClass()` is required, a different approach is needed. Because this would affect more than just a specific domain class, it's best not to use the MetaClass. Instead, I'll use a category.

```
import org.grails.core.AbstractGrailsClass

def klass = grailsApplication.getDomainClass("domainPackage....domain")

def fieldNamesProperty = use(GrailsClassCategory) { klass.getPropertyValue('fieldNames') }

class GrailsClassCategory {
    static Object getPropertyValue(AbstractGrailsClass klass, String name) {
        return ['fieldName','fieldName2']
    }
}
```

The category is used to override `AbstractGrailsClass.getPropertyValue()`.

Comment: +1 I will try this. There is also one more scenario. Another domain does not contain the property fieldNames. But I have to dynamically add it so that the code  grailsApplication.getDomainClass("domainPackage....domain").getPropertyValue('fieldNames') returns some value.

Comment: It can be done the same way. Instead of an empty list return a list with values: `SomeClass.metaClass.static.getFieldNames = { ['fieldname'] }`

Comment: I tried it, its not working. grailsApplication.getDomainClass("domainPackage....domain").getPropertyValue('fi‌​eldNames')  returns null. Even tried at the instance level but it doesn't.

Comment: Please add the code that's not working to the question so i can tell where it's failing.

Comment: `getDomainClass()` is getting in the way. It returns a `DefaultGrailsDomainClass` not the actual domain class. Then it uses `ClassPropertyFetcher` and `PropertyFetcher` to retrieve property values. Now that my head is spinning I ask: why? Is there a reason for using this instead of accessing the domain class directly?

Comment: Don't know. Its the convention followed by other devs. What do you mean by directly accessing domain ? You mean DomainClass.metaclass.properties.... ?

Comment: Also why the second code block doesn't work ? I used domain class directly there.

Comment: I meant ` SomeClass.fieldNames` Your second code block didn't work because you created an instance of the domain class and attempted to access a static property as an instance property. Can you post an example of the spock test?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92647/discussion-between-vivek-sadh-and-emmanuel-rosa).

Comment: The reason why getdomainClass was used is the property can either be present or not. We are not checking just value but checking whether property exist or not.